# How do I check the memory written into a Raspberry Pi Pico W from the compiler?

Tags: c, pi-pico

I'm uploading a simple C program into a Raspberry Pi Pico and I would like to check the memory this program is occupying in the Pico.

The program only has an empty main function. What I want to do is similar to what happens in the Arduino IDE when you upload something to an Arduino Uno. When you do that, the terminal shows the memory occupied by the program and the memory left in the board.

To upload the program to the Pico I'm using Git Bash compiling with a cmake file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get this information because I think it's quite useful but picotool does not support it as a feature. The only thing I found is whether to check the .uf2-file size in the file explorer of your host-PC or use the "save" command of picotool (Page 72 of [this document](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/pico/getting-started-with-pico.pdf)). There you get the actually downloaded bytes of the program stored on pico.

If you have any other recommendations, please let me know!